# What is an NVMe controller?

Tags: pci-express, nvme

This question may sound trivial but it isn't.
Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNhe.png) image.
You can see Windows device manager listing NVMe controllers. I expected it to list NVMe disks but not controllers.

It does not make sense to me because NVMe is a software protocol only. NVMe disks use PCIe. AFAIK they are connected to PCIe directly. There is no storage controller in between.

For example when using SATA there is a SATA AHCI controller on the mainboard connected to PCIe which converts PCIe to physical SATA. There can be multiple disks connected to this controller.

But as already said NVMe is different to SATA as it is only a software protocol. There is no physical NVMe.

So it must be the NVMe controller is virtual and located on the disk.

But why is there a controller at all if it is on the disk and always can only have one disk connected to it? Why does the device manager show two devices while it is logical and physical one?

Can someone please explain what exactly an NVMe controller is and what it does?

Comment: Even SATA disks have controllers on them. In the case of NVMe, it's like the host controller and disk controller become one. There's nothing "virtual" about it (well except maybe namespaces, which are considered "Disk drives").

Comment: "NVMe is a software protocol only" - citation needed

Comment: @TomYan Can you confirm that NVMe is a pure software protocol? Or does it also define any PINs or voltages? Because as far as I know the PINs are defined by M2 and the voltage and so on is defined by PCIe.

Comment: @zomega I think you can say so. This seems to be the lowest level part the the NVMe specs defines: https://nvmexpress.org/developers/nvme-transport-specifications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia
[NVM Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express):

> NVM Express (NVMe) or **Non-Volatile Memory Host Controller
> Interface** Specification (NVMHCIS) is an open, logical-device
> interface specification for accessing a computer's non-volatile
> storage media usually attached via PCI Express (PCIe) bus. The
> initialism NVM stands for non-volatile memory, which is often NAND
> flash memory that comes in several physical form factors, including
> solid-state drives (SSDs), PCIe add-in cards, and M.2 cards, the
> successor to mSATA cards. NVM Express, as a logical-device interface,
> has been designed to capitalize on the low latency and internal
> parallelism of solid-state storage devices.
>
> Architecturally, **the logic for NVMe is physically stored within and
> executed by the NVMe controller chip** that is physically co-located
> with the storage media, usually an SSD. Version changes for NVMe,
> e.g., 1.3 to 1.4, are incorporated within the storage media, and do
> not affect PCIe-compatible components such as motherboards and CPUs.

The computer sees the controller that is on the disk, and the controller
than shows the disk to the computer. The disk itself has no protocol
and can only communicate via its NVMe controller chip.

Comment: 1. Is it possible an NVMe controller has multiple disks? 2. Are you sure the NVMe controller has its own chip separated from the rest of the disk? 3. Why is the NVMe controller chip on the disk and not on the mainboard (as the SATA AHCI controller)? 4. What is the protocol used between the NVMe controller and the NVMe disk (physical and logical)?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. 3. So you don't have to switch motherboards, 4. See the References section of the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: I think I understood now. The NVMe controller is a disk controller and not a bus controller like the SATA HBA. Is that right?

Comment: That's it exactly.

Comment: @zomega `Is it possible an NVMe controller has multiple disks?` Each namespace is considered a "disk" in the OS though. (There's always at least one namespace on each drive so that it can be used, which is the case in most consumer-grade drives.) `So you don't have to switch motherboards` that's a weird way to put / think of it. I think the real question is that why it's made HBA-less / one-HBA-per-drive. I don't have a concrete answer for that, but it's probably because it fits the whole design more this way / is more efficient performance-wise.

Comment: @zomega `What is the protocol used between the NVMe` I don't think there's any particular "protocol". I mean, it's probably not conned any name. It really just manipulates the NAND flash as per the NVMe commands it received.